# Avoid excessive repetition with templated type

Tags: c++, templates

I want to define a generic function whose arguments and the return type are identical instantiations of a template. This leads to an overly verbose definition. Is there a way to use a shorthand without polluting the enclosing namespace?

Example,

```
template<class CoordinateType, class ValueType>
struct PointWithValue {
    CoordinateType x, y;
    ValueType value;
}

template<class CoordinateType, class ValueType>
PointWithValue<CoordinateType, ValueType> interpolate(
    PointWithValue<CoordinateType, ValueType> point1,
    PointWithValue<CoordinateType, ValueType> point2)
{
    ...
}
```

One solution I can come up with is

```
template<class PointWithValueType>
PointWithValueType interpolate(
    PointWithValueType point1, PointWithValueType point2)
```

But I am not really happy with this as it obfuscates what I expect as `PointWithValueType`; it is only implicitly shown inside the body function. And if the caller passes a wrong argument, the error is unlikely to be clear and concise.

I would like something that looks like this

```
template<class CoordinateType, class ValueType>
using PointWithValueType = PointWithValue<CoordinateType, ValueType>;
PointWithValueType interpolate(
    PointWithValueType point1, PointWithValueType point2)
```

As far as I can tell the above only works if I wrap it in a class and define the method as `static`. It kind of works but it also changes the interface (puts the function inside a deeper named scope) and it relies on a class without members and with only a single static function which feels awkward and might confuse the user.

This is a general question, workarounds for this particular problem that do not apply to this class of problem are not suitable answers. Is there something similar to my `using` example without drawbacks?

Comment: In C++14 you can use return type deduction like `template<class CoordinateType, class ValueType>
auto interpolate(...)`

Comment: FWIW you should be putting your types in their own namespace.  If you put a using statement there then it won't pollute the global namespace.

Comment: Just to clarify your requirements, if another class met the requirements of `interpolate`, would you want to explicitly reject that other class and ONLY accept `PointWithValue` arguments or return types? Or would that other class be acceptable input?

Comment: @Timo That's nice small improvement but it doesn't solve the argument problem unfortunately.

Comment: @NathanOliver Correct, I meant to say I don't want to pollute the enclosing namespace.

Comment: @patatahooligan that's why it's only a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @MarkB I am leaning towards only accepting this particular class, but if you have a clean answer for the alternative feel free to add it to the discussion.

Answer (score 5):

With traits and SFINAE, you might do

```
template <typename T>
struct IsPointWithValue : std::false_type {};

template <class CoordinateType, class ValueType>
struct IsPointWithValue<PointWithValue<CoordinateType, ValueType>> : std::true_type
{
// Possibly aliases to retrieve template parameters.
};

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<IsPointWithValue<T>::value, int> = 0>
T interpolate(T point1, T point2);
```

Comment: The members can then be accessed with a structured binding: `auto& [x1, y1, v1] = point1;` so aliases or traits for `CoordinateType` and `ValueType` aren't required (requires C++17).

Comment: @Timo: if the **types** `CoordinateType` and/or `ValueType` are needed, it is a way to go. Maybe the types are like `std::vector` and provides `value_type` alias, but else, you have to work-around that, trait is a convenient way.

Comment: And structure binding is not required to access members (we might access via name).

Comment: I didn't mean to say it has to be used. It's just a convenient way to access the members in a generalized way without having to know their types or names explicitly. My wording was probably not the best.

Comment: This is nice. I haven't used `std::enable_if` so I'll have to read up on it a bit before fully understanding this answer. One question: is there a way to define `IsPointWithValue` so that it is accessible inside this namespace but not outside of it?

Comment: You can place the traits in a namespace named "`details`"/"`internal`" to explicitly inform users that it is not part of public interface. that allow to "hide" it (from your main namespace) even if still accessible.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a good idea to switch to using static assert with dedicated type trait (and probably to a concept with C++20) to check that template parameter is of required kind:

```
template
<
    typename x_MaybePointWithValue
> class
is_point_with_value: public ::std::false_type {};

template
<
    typename CoordinateType
,   typename ValueType
> class
is_point_with_value<PointWithValue<CoordinateType, ValueType>>: public ::std::true_type {};

template
<
    typename x_PointWithValue
> x_PointWithValue
interpolate(x_PointWithValue point1, x_PointWithValue point2)
{
    static_assert
    (
        is_point_with_value<x_PointWithValue>::value
    ,   "template parameter must be an instance of PointWithValue template"
    );
}
```